# Formatting an American Number format to a Integer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know I am asking a dull question but at this point of time it is not dull to me.

I have a number say

`$123,245,123` in my text box on executing the onBlur function this value is when rounded or done mathematical it is showing as `Nan`

How will I format this number to a integer.

```
var value = '$123,245,123'
value = value.Replace?(/[$,]/g, '')
```

please help in correcting my script to avoid NaN

Comment: `+value.replace(/\D/g,'')` fixes everything

Comment: @adeneo: not for values containing dollarcents, like '$123,245,123.23'

Comment: @KooiInc - why not! It could contain rainbows and unicorns, and it would still work ?

Comment: @adeneo: try `+('$123,245,123.23'.replace(/\D/g,''))`. Because `\D` also removes the dot. Result *12324512323* is not *123245123.23*

Comment: @KooiInc - Oh okay, I read *dollarsigns*, but you typed *dollarcents*, and that wouldn't work, but the OP's example has no period, and he's asking for an integer, not a float.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
var value = '$123,245,123'
value = parseFloat(value.replace(/[$,]/g, ''));
```

Comment: value = +parseFloat(value.replace(/[$,]/g, '')); removes the error in this script

Answer (score 1):

try `Number('$123,245,123'.replace(/[$,]/g, ''))`.

That's: `replace` (lowercase r), without `?`

Using `Number`-conversion, values like `'$123,245,123.23'` are also converted (to float)

Instead of `Number`, a simple `+` is equivalent: `+('$123,245,123'.replace(/[$,]/g, ''))`

If you need a check for `NaN`, use something like:

```
var dollarvalue = +('$123,245,123'.replace(/[$,]/g, '')) || 0;
```

If you only want to keep the dollar value (no cents, integer), use

```
(+('$123,245,123.43'.replace(/[$,]/g, ''))).toFixed(0);
```

If you want to round the dollar value, use

```
Math.round(+('$123,245,123.43'.replace(/[$,]/g, '')));
```